# Java REST. Hibernate. Получить список офисов

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

Всем привет.
Допустим, у меня есть класс Organization с lazy полем `Set<Office> offices`, и методом `getOffices`.
Есть класс `Office` с полем `Organization org`. Маппинг OneToMany.
На фронте есть форма Организация. Заполняется через контроллер /organization/{id} (http метод GET);
У формы есть кнопка Посмотреть все её офисы. При нажатии на неё должен открываться список офисов этой организации (как я понимаю, запрашивается `getOffices`).
И вот здесь я не могу сообразить. Мне надо сделать отдельный контроллер для этого запроса? Или как-то по другому.

Comment: в том же классе, где и /organization/{id}  добавьте метод /organization/{id}/offices при вызове которого, вы сможете из репозитория по id доставать все офисы

Comment: Я решил к методу /organization/{id} добавить @RequestParam(required = false) String offices. А в сервисе проверять, if (offices != null), то запрашивать этот список офисов.
В последствии можно будет передавать несколько параметров offices, и запрашивать определённое количество офисов, а не все. Я так думаю. :)

Comment: Если офисов у организации немного, то эффективнее сохранять список в html-документе во время его рендеринга. Если много, то стоит добавить контроллер для отдачи списка офисов.

Comment: Офисы это для примера. Я вообще хотел уточнить, как поступают в случае запроса у объекта списка другого объекта при маппингах OneToMany и ManyToMany. Понял, что реализация зависит от количества элементов списка. Спасибо.

Comment: @Bakhuss с отдельным урлом лучше будет выглядеть запросов офисом с параметрами фильтрации, например /organization/{id}/offices?limit=10&page=0&order=asc